# Como fazer para converter uma data no formato americano no Angular?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, data

Estou usando uma resposta Json No Laravel 5, onde uso o Angular para poder exibir esses dados.

A data no Laravel é retornada no formato `2017-05-17 15:56:46`. Ao tentar usar o filtro `date` no angular, continuou exibido a mesma coisa:

```js
angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
 {{ '2017-05-17 15:56:46' | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
</div>
```

Em casos de datas no formato acima, como eu deveria fazer para poder converter para o formato `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: Você não tem a opção de formatar a data direto no php? Eu estava sofrendo muito com isso também e resolvi formatando a data no momento do `select`.

Comment: @celsomtrindade to pensando em tentar fazer o `Carbon::setToStringFormat` funcionar, mas tá osso

Comment: Confesso que não conheço muito de Laravel, mas o que eu fiz foi `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data '%d/%m/%Y') as 'data'`. A não ser que você precise trabalhar com a data diretamente na view, ai nesse caso não sei se isso serviria.

Comment: @celsomtrindade minha preocupação principal é realmente chegar a um padrão. Eu poderia solucionar assim, mas toda vez que precisasse da data formatada, teria que ficar repetindo isso.

Comment: Pois é, esse é um dos contras desse método. Dê uma olhada nesse [módulo](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment), utilizei quando precisei trabalhar com diversas manipulações de data, inclusive mostrar mensagens como "a 17min atrás". Segue a mesma lógica da resposta do amigo jbueno.

Comment: @celsomtrindade to pensando nessa iniciativa também. Sugiro que poste uma resposta com o Angular Moment. É uma alternativa excelente!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso que você pôs na *view* é uma `string` e não uma data. O filtro [`date`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) só pode ser aplicado em objetos do tipo [`date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('mainController', mainCtrlFn);

function mainCtrlFn() {
    this.data = new Date();
    this.dataLaravel = new Date('2017-05-17 15:56:46');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
 {{ mainCtrl.data | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }} <br>
 {{ mainCtrl.dataLaravel | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Conforme conversado nos comentários, e também como resposta alternativa, podemos utilizar um módulo para aprimorar o trabalho com datas no AngularJS.

Seria o módulo [Angular-Moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment).

Ele possui diversos benefícios, como:

- Definir o locale para as datas
- Escolher o modo de exibição através de filtro (semelhante a resposta do jbueno) `{{ date | amDateFormat:'MM.DD.YYYY HH:mm:ss' }}`
- Definir diferença em UTC, etc. `{{ date | amUtcOffset:'+0300' }}`
- Criar mensagens de tempo já decorrido, ex.: "a 17 min atrás" `{{ <span am-time-ago="date | amParse:'YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:ss'"></span> }}`

Entre outras funcionalidades excelentes!

Lógico, vai depender da necessidade e escopo do projeto, mas é uma boa alternativa.