# Como formatar data para o formato dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A data que tenho esta assim:

> "Fri Sep 22 2017 14:42:35 GMT-0300"

Preciso formatar ela para o seguinte formato:

> dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Como eu poderia fazer isso usando JavaScript ou Angular?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [Como fazer para converter uma data no formato americano no Angular?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205603/18246)

Comment: essas datas estão assim "Fri Sep 22 2017 14:42:35 GMT-0300"?

Comment: Pelo formato da data não considero duplicata pelos links acima

Comment: Data não tem formato.

Comment: Ok  data não tem formato, mas eu considero que os links não responde a pergunta.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tempos precisei disso, então fiz o básico:

```
<script>
var data = new Date("Fri Sep 22 2017 14:42:35 GMT-0300");
var dia = data.getDate(); dia = zeroAEsquerda(dia, 2);
var mescru = data.getMonth();var mes = data.getMonth(); mes += 1; mes = zeroAEsquerda(mes, 2);
var ano = data.getFullYear();
var dataAtual = dia+'/'+mes+'/'+ano;
var horaAtual       = data.getHours();          // 0-23
var minutoAtual     = data.getMinutes();        // 0-59
var segundoAtual    = data.getSeconds();        // 0-59
console.log('Data: '+dia+'/'+mes+'/'+ano+' - '+horaAtual+':'+minutoAtual+':'+segundoAtual);
function zeroAEsquerda(str, length) {
  const resto = length - String(str).length;
  return '0'.repeat(resto > 0 ? resto : '0') + str;
}
</script>
```