# Data e hora no formato Brasileiro dd/mm/AAAA HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript

Só abri essa pergunta porque todas as respostas que encontrei criam funções ou vão por caminhos muito longos para respondê-la.

O fato é: preciso de data e hora no formato brasileiro:

```
dd/mm/AAAA HH:MM:SS
```

Comment: As "funções e caminhos muito longos" existem por vários motivos. O principal é que a API nativa de datas do JavaScript [nunca foi lá muito boa](https://codeofmatt.com/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/). E o método `toLocaleString()` pode retornar outro formato caso o usuário não tenha o locale correto instalado em sua máquina (nesse caso usará o locale *default* do sistema). E tem o caso - mais raro hoje em dia, mas ainda sim pode acontecer - do formato relativo ao locale mudar (afinal, é uma aproximação do que é usado no dia-a-dia, e nada impede que a definição mude).

Comment: Eu só quis esclarecer alguns pontos com relação ao uso de "funções e caminhos longos" (que não é algo "ruim" nem feito à toa) e em nenhum momento insinuei que sua pergunta não é útil. Desculpe se passei a impressão errada. Só achei importante comentar os pontos com relação a `toLocaleString` (cuja solução que vc postou não está errada, é apenas um ponto de atenção - não é 100% garantido que **sempre** retornará o mesmo formato, pelos motivos já explicados no comentário acima). Se quiser, pode editar sua resposta adicionando essa informação, assim ela se torna ainda mais útil.

Comment: Outro ponto é que já existem **várias** perguntas sobre formatação de datas em JavaScript, como [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239813/112052) e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6526/112052). Se não achou uma resposta exatamente igual a sua, seria melhor responder uma das perguntas já existentes em vez de duplicar a pergunta (e isso seria bem mais útil, pois uma delas é um dos primeiros resultados no Google para "formatar datas JavaScript"). Não tem pq criar outra pergunta para cada variação mínima de formato, a não ser que exija uma solução muito diferente do que já foi proposta.

Comment: E sua resposta é basicamente "use este código", sem nenhuma explicação, e respostas assim são menos úteis do que aquelas que explicam as coisas. E não precisa ser um livro, qualquer explicação mínima já torna a resposta mais útil do que está atualmente. Por exemplo, por que o parâmetro deve ser `'pt-br'`? Posso passar qualquer string? Tem limitações/casos especiais? etc. Não adianta ser claro e direto se a resposta não explica nada, as melhores respostas (as mais úteis) são justamente as que explicam porque o código funciona, os conceitos por trás dele, etc.

Comment: Em vez de ficar perplexo, por que não tentar entender melhor como o site funciona? Veja [ask], [answer] e o [FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/112052). Entenda que **somente** a utilidade não é suficiente, pois existe um [escopo bem definido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) sobre o que pode e [o que não pode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) ser perguntado. Claro que cada um tem seu critério próprio sobre o que é uma boa pergunta, mas o escopo e todos os links que passei existem para tentar uniformizar o máximo possível, de forma a minimizar as divergências.

Comment: É claro que o sistema de votação não é perfeito e podem ocorrer casos estranhos e "injustos", mas **de modo geral**, eu diria que funciona bem. Por fim, se discorda de algo e quiser levar adiante a discussão, pode abrir um tópico no [meta], pois lá serve para discutir justamente esse tipo de coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então depois de muito procurar achei a solução:

```
var agora = new Date();
agora.toLocaleString("pt-br");
console.log(agora);

//     18/03/2019 16:45:00
```

Answer (score 0):

tenta isso:

```
function now(){
    let date = new Date(); 
    let hour = document.querySelector('#hour'); // select the element for print (DOM)
    hour.textContent = data.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');
}
let autorefresh = setInterval(now, 1000);
```